# Authentication Required while executing Selenium "AndroidWebdriver" test

Tags: android, selenium, android-emulator, proxy, webdriver

I Recently started learning selenium "Android Webdriver" 
I'm getting "Authentication required" when JUnit test case is executing

I ensured below things are working fine 
- Since I'm working in office,I have faced "Internet behind Proxy" issue(Authentication Issue).. Later i have resolved and could access internet through emulator now
- jetty is connected with client (Ensured here localhost:8080/wd/hub)

I'm getting authentication error by executing below simple code (i'm sure code is correct)

```
WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();    
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

One thing i'm sure that this is a proxy problem that too during execution only (Client to server connection).. Because I could access Internet in "Androidbrowser" emulator in idle condition.. I dont know why i'm getting "Authentication error" during execution of JUnit

Did i miss to add any library files, codes which resolves proxy problem..

Could any one please help me..?
Your help will be highly appreciated